# how to write unit test case for subscribe in angular constructor?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular11

I want to write a unit test case for subscribe in constructor, I am doing like below, and it is saying that SUCCESS on running `ng test` but I cannot see this in code coverage.

I request you to please check and let me know what I am doing wrong, as I am very new to writing test cases. Thanks in advance.

**component.ts:**

```
public  public mockData$ = this.mockData.asObservable();
constructor(public testService: TestService){
 const mockSubcription = this.testService.mockData$.subscribe(data => {
 //data: {"name":"testName","age":40}
 
 /* ----- */
 }  }
```

**spec.ts:**

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    testService = TestBed.inject(TestService);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
   fit('should call mockData subscribe', () => {
    TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    let spy = spyOn(component.testService.mockData$, 'subscribe').and.callThrough();
    expect(spy).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Comment: I think the constructor is not the right place to make your subscription!
Move it to the onInit method